# Can a website have multiple CNAME?

Tags: cname

We have a subdomain of our site which has hubspot installed on it so the CNAME used is of hubspot. We are trying another software (unbounce) which integrates with hubspot. The problem is its asking to set CNAMEs to have a entry of unbouncepages.com. Can a website have both hubspot and unbounce CNAME entries?

Comment: Setting CNAME is also mean setting Subdomain

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

In fact, you probably already have multiple CNAME records. (eg. you'll probably already have one for `www`.) However, you can't have the same *name* pointing to different *canonical names* (one to many) - if that is what you mean.

*hubspot* and *unbounce* will need to have different *source names*.

CNAME records are associated with the domain's DNS. Not the "website".

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, no and no.**

**Yes**, You can have plenty of unique cnames. E.g. `www.` and `preview.` of the domain `example.com` are allowed. You can have as many as you want, but:
**No**, you can not have multiple CNAMEs with the same values. You can have `www.`, `www.preview.` and `preview.` at the same time, but two times `www.` isnt not allowed, so:
**No**, if you want IPv4 *and* IPv6 you can't use CNAMEs. Because you can't have two identical cnames, you have to enter two A-records, one for IPv6 and one forIPv4.

Comment: "No, if you want IPv4 and IPv6 you can't use CNAMEs. ... you have to enter two A-records, one for IPv6 and one forIPv4."  this is not clear or wrong. First IPv6 addresses use `AAAA`  records, not `A` records. Then you can totally have `x CNAME y` and `x A ...` plus `x AAAA ...`  so that at the end both `x` and `y` name have one IPv4 and one IPv6 address (more can be added of course)

Comment: Feel free to add/edit some simple examples if you want to :)

Comment: My comment as is is wrong, I should have written `y A ....` and `y AAAA ...` because `x` can not have any other records once it has a `CNAME`. But the conclusion stands: at the end, both `x` and `y` will have one IPv4 and one IPv6 address resolved for it (both of them, due to the `CNAME` record)

Answer (score 1):

Yes

We currently use Wishpond and Unbounce to create landing pages.

As mentioned by the others, the CNAMES just need to be different obviously.

So we use **go**.ourdomain.com for Wishpond and **get**.ourdomain.com for Unbounce.